# Can I use a network drive that's connected to a router being used as a switch?

Tags: networking, router, external-hard-drive, switch

Here is my current setup:

*Modem -> Google Wifi router -> Linksys EA7500 used as a switch*

What I'd like to set up is this

*Modem -> Google Wifi router -> Linksys EA7500 -> network drive through USB port*

I can successfully use the Linksys router as a switch, but when I connect a hard drive to the usb port to use it as a network drive, it doesn't appear on the network.

1. Should this configuration be possible, or can I only use the usb ports of the Linksys router when it's actually used as the primary router?
2. If possible, what steps should I take to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is the networkdrive on the router plug'n play? If not you need to set it up first. The Linksys manual will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to make sure that the router is addressable on the network, i.e. the IP address of the EA7500 must be on your subnet. Otherwise you will not be able to access your file server.

You also must enable all sorts of things in the EA7500's web interface. That too is a reason why you must be able to connect to that web-interface.

When you're in the EA7500's webinterface, make sure DHCP is disabled if your google-router does dhcp.

Comment: That worked. The Google router was on 192.168.86.1, so within the Linksys router's config I set it to run on IP 192.168.86.2. I believe this is on the same subnet but outside of the DHCP range (which is 20-250). Anyway, it seems to work as I can find the network drive now.